# Artifacts when layering

Tags: artifacts

I'm learning blender and ran into a problem. When applying layers, artifacts appear. Tell me how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your replies and good luck everyone!

[image]

Comment: File path https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A4Em-9DBDJ-pfU_Ih3pEUFGAwg9o3_t4/view?usp=share_link

Comment: That's called Z-fighting and occurs because you have two faces in exactly the same position so that Blender doesn't know which to display. It's difficult to suggest a way to get over that here. You could possibly convert the curves to meshes and then boolean them together but that would still require some cleaning up of the mesh to get a good result.

Comment: i fixed it. I built the element from scratch and combined the details. thanks for the comment